# PromQL: как выбрать по маске labels в Grafana?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

Есть запрос, который выбирает по маске метрики (_sli) и по маске хоста данные в Grafana через запрос PromQL.

```
({__name__=~".+\\_sli",host=~"(\\d{4}serv1\\d{2}.+)"})
```

Можно ли к этому запросу добавить условие, что в имени метки (то, что в Grafana называется labels) содержится часть строки? Не могу понять, как в запросе указать, что это метка и что нужно выбрать только определенные labels у которых в имени есть, например "test"

Comment: Можете пояснить что именно вы хотите сделать? Отфильтровать список лейблов которые вернутся? Отфильтровать по наличию хотя бы одного лейбла со словом test в имени? Что-то иное?

Comment: Отфильтровать список лейблов которые вернутся